# AngularJS - Routing crash after changing path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

My problem is that when I change the path of my angular app nearly 1 of 10 tries the routing crashes.
Let me explain it a little bit closer. With the crash I mean that the route is changing to the new path but nearly at the same time the URL loses the #

Conroller which is triggered after clicking at a html div with the ng-click:

```
$scope.showDetailOfEntry = function(id){
    $location.path('/detail/' + id);
}
```

Routing:

```
.when('/detail/:id', {
        title: "Detail-View",
        name: "detail",
        templateUrl: "./templates/detail.php",
        controller: "DetailController"
})
```

About 9/10 tries the path change is running without any problem.

The URL should be:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/#/detail/66
```

But turns into this:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/detail/66
```

I think the problem is located at the `$location.path();`- Maybe it gets sometimes into term problems.

Do you have any idea why this is sometimes happening?
Thank you for your help! I would appreciate every answer.

Comment: Can you show your app's config()  fully please?

Comment: In my app config are only .when(). No html5 mode or something. I have about 20-25 .when() Should I put these lines all into my question?

Comment: Try $location.url('/detail/' + id) instead of path()

Comment: Same behaviour. Sometimes it runs into the crash. ~90% not.

Comment: Is there anything in the console?

Comment: No, isn't because the `http://localhost/MyApp/detail/66` does not exist. But the back button works. If I click at the back button I get to the correct link `http://localhost/MyApp/#/detail/66`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue referenced to in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8675 and https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10659

A proposed (temporary) fix for this could be:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
})
```

That is, until the AngularJS team finds a proper fix.